# Automatic discrimination between files according to date

Tags: matlab, file, validation, input, automated-tests

If I state my input folder in this way:

```
inputFolder = 'C:\myFolder\myData'
```

and within `'myData'` there are the following files:

```
Car20150722.xls
Bus20150722.xls
Car20150721.xls
Bus20150721.xls
```

how do I specify `inputFile= MODEyyyymmdd` where I can specify whether the MODE is `Car` or `Bus` but it will always choose the file with the *latest date*.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have those `yyyymmdd` and `MODE` values in variables? What do you want to do with the file? Do you only need to build a string with the file name?

Comment: Yes. I would state MODE= Car, for example, and it would automatically assign inputFile=Car20150722 because that is the latest dated file for MODE = Car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to get a list of the file names

```
mode = 'Car';  %// or Bus or whatever

files = dir([mode, '*.xls']);
names = {files.name};
```

now extract the date, note that the date is always the 8 characters starting 12 characters from the end (and convert it to a serial date number while we're at it)

```
dates = cellfun(@(x)(datenum(x(end-11:end-4),'yyyymmdd')),names);
```

and then find the position of the max:

```
[~,idx] = max(dates)
```

and finally get the corresponding file name:

```
filename = names(idx)
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! The only thing I would change would be to include formatIn option to allow it to read the date. dates = cellfun(@(x)(datenum(x(end-11:end-4),'yyyymmdd')),names);

Comment: If there is a way to specify the folder without using cd, that would be useful to know if you could show?

Comment: @Mary I would guess you could just make that part of the input for `dir` e.g. `dir('C:\myFolder\myData\', [mode, '*.xls'])`?

Comment: `dir(['C:\myFolder\myData\', mode, '*.xls'])` works, thanks.